# Packet loss at irregular intervals

Tags: firewall

We have had significant packet loss issues since switching from Sophos UTM SG 310 to the Barracuda Cloud Gen F380 firewall. This has a big impact on live applications like telephony. It is noticeable that CPU load peaks are logged again and again. Various optimizations have already been made, but thousands of packets are lost every few days in a short period of time.
We have already set the NIC buffers to the maximum. The physical ports have changed. QoS was already set during commissioning. CPU load distribution of the ports has been changed. According to Barracuda support, our configuration looks fine, but our problem persists.
Brief information:

- about 50 employees
- approx 25-35 VPN clients
- 3 STS VPN connections
- Operation of a small call center

Comment: Where is the packet loss? VPN? Internet access/SNAT? DMZ public access/DNAT? Any hint to what's loading the CPU?

Comment: Are you measuring packet loss using the discard counters on the Barracuda using e.g. SNMP; and do you have a time-series graph to analyze?  Do substantially all of the incidents of packet loss correlate to incidents of CPU spikes?  Do you have drops in all QoS queues or only some of them?

Comment: Is the barracuda overloaded?  Do drops happen at high loads?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. The setting is current: P1 internal network P4 Internet access P7 VPN and web server

The packet loss occurs on all ports, with P4 being more severely affected. The CPU load is often high in connection with the packet loss. But it has also happened that packets were lost without the load increasing significantly. The drops are logged in the statistic of the Barracuda and also in our PRTG in a time series graph.

Comment: Have you monitored the number of sessions on the Barracuda? The F380B is spec'ed for 400,000 concurrent sessions which seems quite luxurious for ~80 users - unless they're all power users.